# Linking CSS in a HTML file

Tags: html, css

I started coding around last month and am using Atom Text Editor. I can't seem to link my CSS code to my HTML

here's a screenshot

[image]

The CSS file is in the same folder as the HTML file and I've put in the exact name in the href part.

Here's my CSS.

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./index.css">`

Answer (score 0):

This is how you troubleshoot HTML and CSS:

1. Open your index.html in a browser. E.g.: Chrome
2. Open Developer Tools. In the case of Chrome, right click and click Inspect in the menu.
3. You will be shown something like the image below.

[image: Developer tools in Elements tab]

4. In the elements tab, check in the `<head>` and check that your stylesheet is included.
5. If it is included, click on the link to see if it opens up a new page with the styles in it as raw text.

e.g.: https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/primary-unified.css?v=7f46f0b7e1bb

6. If it is not, you should be playing around with above answers regarding paths.
7. As an alternative, try including the styles directly into the `<head>` like this:

```html
    <head>
      <style type="text/css">
        body {
          background-color: blue;
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      <h1>Test</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
    </body>
```

Comment: Let me know if you have any questions. The purpose of the answers is that every answer should give you different insights into your problem to help you solve it

Answer (score 0):

Without more accurate specification, we can try to solve generally all troubles. These are my advices. 
1 Be careful saving your files before uploading.

2 Link stylesheet with relative paths like the posts before.

3 add ‘file version’ of your css script. In this way your browser will reload all css styles. (Very important for you and all your user in future when editing templates)
Simply add this in link stylesheet html tag

```
version=1.3
```

And change values every time you edit css and upload files

4 *testing css* you could test your css working with `element inspector` of your browser.

Hope it will be useful!

Answer (score -1):

I think you did not save your project(blue Dot on the tab). First save your project by Ctrl+S and the review the page.

Comment: Sometimes there is a spaces before/after the name if you copy it so keep this in mind also.

Answer (score -1):

Close the html tag at the end & be sure to save both the files in same folder